# Some vector elements do not change

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am experiencing very strange behaviour, which I cannot explain. I hope someone might shed some light on it.

Code snippet first:

```
class TContour {
public:
  typedef std::pair<int,int> TEdge;   // an edge is defined by indices of vertices
  typedef std::vector<TEdge> TEdges;

  TEdges m_oEdges;

  void splitEdge(int iEdgeIndex, int iMiddleVertexIndex) {
    TEdge & oEdge = m_oEdges[iEdgeIndex];
    m_oEdges.push_back(TEdge(oEdge.first, iMiddleVertexIndex));
    oEdge = TEdge(oEdge.second, iMiddleVertexIndex);          // !!! THE PROBLEM
  };

  void splitAllEdges(void) {
    size_t iEdgesCnt = m_oEdges.size();
    for (int i=0; i<iEdgesCnt; ++i) {
      int iSomeVertexIndex = 10000;  // some new value, not actually important
      splitEdge(i, iSomeVertexIndex);
    }
  };
};
```

When I call `splitAllEdges()`, the original edges are changed and new edges are added (resulting in doubling the container size). Everything as expected, with an exception of 1 original edge, which does not change. Should that be of any interest, its index is `3` and value is `[1,242]`. All the other original edges change, but this one remains unchanged. Adding debug prints confirms that the edge is written with a different value, but `m_oEdges` contents does not change.

I have a simple workaround, replacing the problematic line with `m_oEdges[iEdgeIndex] = TEdge(oEdge.end, iMiddleVertexIndex);` does fix the issue. Though my concern is what is the cause for the unexpected behaviour. Might that be a compiler bug (hence what other issues do I have to expect?), or do I overlook some stupid bug in my code?

```
/usr/bin/c++ --version
c++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

Switching from c++98 to c++11 did not change anything.

Comment: References to vector element can be invalidated after a call to push_back

Comment: OT: Aren't the members of a `std::pair` named `first` / `second` (rather than `start` / `end`)?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Sure they are, thanks for your note. Fixed the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an invalid reference after your push_back operation.

This:

```
TEdge & oEdge = m_oEdges[iEdgeIndex];
```

acquires the reference. Then this:

```
m_oEdges.push_back(TEdge(oEdge.start, iMiddleVertexIndex));
```

potentially *resizes* the vector, and in so doing, invalidates the `oEdge` reference. At which point this:

```
oEdge = TEdge(oEdge.end, iMiddleVertexIndex);
```

is no longer define behavior, as you're using a dangling reference. Reuse the index, not the reference, such as:

```
m_oEdges[iEdgeIndex] = TEdge(m_oEdges[iEdgeIndex].end, iMiddleVertexIndex);
```

Comment: Wow. Now that you're saying that, it's perfectly logical, I'm ashamed I didn't realize it myself. Trying to blame someone else, I first thought this should be noted in the operator[](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) documentation. But it surely is documented somewhere, and it is definitely subject to experience with the std containers, which I still need to learn. Well, thanks for helping me with that!

Comment: @yman Trie [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. Ex: `push_back` is documented with: "If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated." Honestly, it's arguably the very best C++ reference site on the web, is constantly being groomed and improved, and is maintained by people incredibly familiar with the standards. Definitely worthy of a permanent bookmark in your toolbar. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned the invalidation of the reference, so I won't go into more details on that.

If performance is critical, you could explicitly reserve enough space in the original vector for the new edges before you start looping. This would avoid the problem, but would still be technically incorrect. i.e. it would work, but still be against the rules.

A safer, but slightly slower method would be to iterate through the vector, changing existing edges and generating new edges in a new vector (with sufficient space reserved beforehand for performance), and then at the end, append the new vector to the existing one.

The **safest** way (including being completely exception safe), would be to create a new vector (reserving double the size of the initial vector), iterate through the initial vector (without modifying any of its edges), pushing **two** new edges into the new vector for each old edge, and then right at the end vector.swap() the old vector with the new vector.

A big positive side-effect of this last approach is that your code either succeeds completely, or leaves the original edges unchanged. It maintains the integrity of the data even in the face of disaster.

P.S. I notice that you are doing:

```
TEdge(oEdge.first, iMiddleVertexIndex)
TEdge(oEdge.second, iMiddleVertexIndex)
```

If the rest of your code is sensitive to ring-orientation you probably want to reverse the parameters for the second edge. i.e.:

```
TEdge(oEdge.first,        iMiddleVertexIndex)
TEdge(iMiddleVertexIndex, oEdge.second      )
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting alternative ways. I do not actually know the final size in my real application, the snippet was simplified in this manner. So reserving double size might be potentially wasteful. But your point is clear and valid, I like it. P.S. Ring-orientation is no issue for me.